# How to fix ---->warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive

Tags: c

***When I try to run this code***

`#include<stdio.h> int main(){  int a,b,i;  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);     printf("sum is %d\n", a+b);     return 0; }`

**it cannot compile and shows this message bellow**

> main.c:1:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]

Comment: from `int main` on a new line and write the next line.

Comment: `#include` directives (or, for that matter, *any* preprocessing directives), must be on their own lines.

Answer (score 1):

Directives must be separate and one below the other. On the other hand, in this code the variable i is unnecessary.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){  
    int a,b;  
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);     
    printf("sum is %d\n", a+b);     
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#include` directive should have a space after it, and `int main()` should be on a separate line from the include directive.

Comment: I wrote that code keeping #include <stdio.h>
single line 
but when paste it on a <input> field 
the whole code just lost all line break and all code collapse one a single line

Comment: "*`#include` should have a space after it*" no, this is not necessary.